# openapi - Return a file upon simple get request

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to create a rest api, that, given a get request, returns a file. The contents of the file can be a text based format, like xml or json but it can also be binary. For this reason I just want to return the file as is and "let the client deal with it".

The issue that I am facing is, that the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) seems to be unable to parse an open file, that is defined in the response section of an endpoint in any way, and always just returns an empty section.
What I expected to see is at least some sort of binary representation within the json based response body.

So far I have created the following .yml file for the specification:

The URI /schema/{family}/{version}' is meant to return a file corresponding to family and version.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: simple service
  license:
    name: Proprietary
  title: some title
  version: 1.0.0
externalDocs:
  description: Design file can be found in wiki
  url: https://somewhere.else/wiki
servers:
- url: http://localhost:9091/manager/v1
tags:
- name: manager
  description: TODO add a description
  
paths:
  /schemas:
    get:
      operationId: SchemaList
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaName'
          description: successful
        "500":
          description: internal server error
        "503":
          description: service unavailable          
      summary: get list of schema families
      description: gets the top level overview over families of schemas
      tags:
        - schema
  '/schema/{family}':
    get:
      operationId: FamilyList
      parameters:
        - name: family
          in: path
          description: name of the family
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaName'
          description: successful
        "500":
          description: internal server error
        "503":
          description: service unavailable          
      summary: get list of schemas belonging to a schema family
      tags:
        - schema
  '/schema/{family}/{version}':
    get:
      operationId: SchemaFile
      parameters:
        - name: family
          in: path
          description: name of the family
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: version
          in: path
          description: version of file within family of schemas
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaFile'
          description: successful
        "500":
          description: internal server error
        "503":
          description: service unavailable          
      summary: get schema of a certain family in a certain version
      tags:
        - schema  
components:
  schemas:
    SchemaName:
      title: SchemaName
      description: representation of a schema family
      type: object
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          example: "myLittleSchema"
    SchemaFile:
      title: SchemaFile
      description: a schema file, either a single file or a archive (e.g. a .zip)
      type: object
      required:
        - name
        - file
      properties:
        name:
          description: filename
          type: string
          example: "yourFile.txt"
        file:
          description: the file itself
          type: string
          format: binary
```

Using the openapi-generator's [jar file](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#13---download-jar) I can generate a valid go server with

`java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i rest_api.yml -g go-server -o .`

The resulting runnable go project contains a go/ directory where I can plug in my business logic in the _service.go files, in this case the function `SchemaFile()`. I filled it for testing purposes as follows:

```
const fakeFile string = "/home/user/existingfile.txt"

// SchemaFile - get schema of a certain family in a certain version
func (s *SchemaApiService) SchemaFile(ctx context.Context, family string, version string) (ImplResponse, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(fakeFile)
    fmt.Printf("name: %s\nfile: %v\nerr: %v\n", fakeFile, file, err)
    if err != nil {
        return Response(500, nil), errors.New("file not found")
    }
    return Response(http.StatusOK, SchemaFile{Name: fakeFile, File: file}), nil
}
```

To test the output I used curl, but, like with a browser e.g. Chrome, I get an empty response section for the "file":

```
$ curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8080/manager/v1/schema/A/b' -H 'accept: application/octet-stream'
{"name":"/home/user/existingfile.txt","file":{}}
```

What am I missing? Is returning an actual binary file content simply not within the scope of how openapi is meant to be used? Is the generator simply not implemented in the way to deal with an *os.File object that it most certainly understood to put in as an expected type for its response struct?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I changed the type for the file schema from binary to byte, i.e.:

```
        file:
          description: the file itself
          type: string
          format: byte
```

This changes the generated service stub over which I can return something from *os.File to string, as it expects me to return base64 code.
That obviously works, but I find it slightly depressing to use base64 for something I was expecting to work in proper raw byte data.

Comment: As far as I can tell it generated the server stub around net/http.